# Riemann Integrability and sign

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Given a function $f: [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as
$f(x)= x$ if $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $-x$ if $x\notin \mathbb{Q}$. I've been told that
given the upper $(U(f,D))$ and lower sums $(L(f,D))$ of $f$ for any partition P, we have that
$U(f,D)\geq \int^{1}_{0}x dx$
and $L(f,D)\leq \int^{1}_{0} -x dx$. 
May someone elaborate on why the $-x$ term appeared in the second one, please? I do not want a geometric argument.

Answer (score 0):

Let $D=\{a_0=0,a_1,\ldots,a_n=1\}$, with $a_0<a_1<\cdots<a_n$ be a partition of $[0,1]$. Then, for each $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$,$$\sup_{x\in[a_{k-1},a_k]}f(x)=a_k=\operatorname{Id}(a_k)$$and$$\inf_{x\in[a_{k-1},a_k]}f(x)=-a_k=-\operatorname{Id}(a_k).$$But then\begin{align}U(f,D)&=a_1(a_1-a_0)+a_2(a_2-a_1)+\cdots+a_n(a_n-a_{n-1})\\&=U(\operatorname{Id},D)\\&\geqslant\int_0^1x\,\mathrm dx\end{align}and, by a similar argument,$$L(f,D)\leqslant\int_0^1-x\,\mathrm dx.$$

Comment: i'm still not quite sure why the $-x$ term appears, why not just $L(f,D)\leq \int^{1}_{0}xdx$?

Comment: That inequality holds, yes, but it is trivial, snce $L(f,D)\leqslant0$ and $0\leqslant\int_0^1x\,\mathrm dx$. The minus sign comes from the fact that $\inf_{x\in[a_{k-1},a_k]}f(x)=\color{red}{-}a_k$.

Comment: aha $L(f,D)=-U(f,D)$.That is why the inequality holds, right?

Comment: For this function, yes, that is correct.

Comment: Carlos Santos, can this be generalized to $g(x)=f(x)$ when $x$ is rational and $-f(x)$ when $x$ is irrational on the interval $[0,a]$ where $a>0$? under what conditions would it hold?

Comment: The function $g$ is simply $g(x)=x$. For that function, the statement $L(f,D)\leqslant\int_0^1-x\,\mathrm dx$ is false.

Comment: *What* holds for that function $f$? Is it $L(f,D)\leqslant\int_0^{\pi/2}-f(x)\,\mathrm dx$?